# Unable to generate correct application cryptogram

Tags: smartcard, apdu, emv

I am successfully getting Generate Command response

```
[9F02 06   (Amount, authorized, numeric)]:   000000003000 
[9F03 06   (Amount, other, numeric)]:        000000000000 
[9F1A 02   (Terminal country code)]:         0826 
[95 05     (Terminal verification results)]: 0000000000
[5F2A 02   (Transaction currency code)]:     0826 
[9A 03     (Transaction date)]:              150724 (2015-05-28)
[9C 01     (Transaction type)]:              00 
[9F37 04   (Unpredictable number)]:          12345678
```

And the command is

```
80 AE 4000 1D 000000003000 000000000000 0826 0000000000 0826 150724 00 12345678 00
```

With sucessful response

```
8012800008d2715ae1b83027db06020103a0b0009000

Cryptogram Information Data : 00
Application Transaction Counter : 0008
Application Cryptogram : d2715ae1b83027db
Issuer Application Data : 06020103a0b000
```

Everything is good, but whenever I perform transaction in the test environment I get

> The Application Cryptogram was incorrect.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You did not tell which card / card brand you are using. Because of this different "Key Derivation Methods", "Key Derivation Data" and "Transaction Data" should be used for cryptogram calculation. To be simple there are several ARQC/ARPC algorithms used in the world of payments. I hope you are talking about test card and your test environment know the correct UDK or Master Key (MK) to check Cryptogram.

Comment: @iso8583.infosupport I am using AMex card with test environment. But i am not using any key

Comment: Does test description specify the transaction date to be used? If yes, then why you have 9AF3 == 150724  and date in the comment (2015-05-28)?

Answer (score 2):

First of all in your data sample "Transaction date" in packed YYMMDD format is not the same value as in human readable format (YYYY-MM-DD). Dates are different.

If you sent incorrect transaction data or transaction data not related to this ARQC you will fail Cryptogram validation at the host environment.

> Because of using Amount 30.00 with Amex test cases, the card detected
>   as "AEIPS 20 TEST CARD" from Amex Global set.
>
> Recalculation of ARQC using the "Transaction data" gave me the same
>   value as in your card response - 0x9F26 = "d2715ae1b83027db". So, it is
>   confirmed.
>
> ARPC in this case will be "3784BAE0B266DF17".

Certified test environments or Amex Test System (ATS) itself can provide you the ARQC/ARPC recalculation details. Sure if test environment can validate your card brand.

Issue usually in the financial message and Transaction data inside which developers incorrectly packed for external test host validation. (As in your original request.)

Take full trace of transaction from card, thru terminal to host system and you will get where is data misplacement.

Comment: They are showing me recalculated cryptogram which is "2C 36 CA 56 E1 35 BB DC" against my cryptogram "d2715ae1b83027db". if i use their cryptogram they validate the request but i tried my best to generate same cryptogram same like them but fails. can you please suggest something